# How to reference the index column of a pandas dataframe in a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't figure out how to get this code to run properly.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('TradeSheet2.csv', engine='python', sep=r'\s*,\s*', index_col='Symbol', header=0, encoding='ascii')
buy_sig = df1.loc[df1.Total >= 20]
sell_sig = df1.loc[df1.Total <= -20]
df2 = pd.read_csv('Header_Col.csv', index_col='Symbol')

def create_long():
    global df2
    dfnewlong = pd.concat([df2, buy_sig]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
    print(dfnewlong)
    print(dfnewlong.index)
    dfnewlong.set_index('Symbol', inplace=True, drop=False)
    dfnewlong['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfnewlong['DateTime'])
    dfnewlong['Long_Short'] = dfnewlong['Long_Short'].fillna('Long')
    dfnewlong.Symbol = dfnewlong.Symbol.str.strip()
    ticker = dfnewlong['Symbol']
    livequote = si.get_live_price(ticker)
    dfnewlong['Entry_Price'] = dfnewlong['Entry_Price'].fillna(livequote)
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, dfnewlong])
    print(df2.columns)

create_long()
```

I keep getting the error: "`KeyError: "None of ['Symbol'] are in the columns`"

What I'm trying to accomplish is for the function to pull the stock symbols into the variables, but it doesn't seem to work because the stock symbols are in the index column.

Links to the files being used by the code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1prqdn9l7wnA5hg2gKqGeubeWLo5kRvI6/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vkFZYBPJqWzjcYPJFKyRHIMLkg5zJ7Oy/view?usp=sharing

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `reset_index` first, since you already set `Symbol` as index:

```
print(dfnewlong.index)
dfnewlong.reset_index(inplace=True) # <----- here
#dfnewlong.set_index('Symbol', inplace=True, drop=False)
```

Also you can remove the next line (the `set_index` call) if you want to unset 'Symbol' as index columns